# Laptop turns off immediately after I turn it on

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, cleaning, capacitor

My laptop was having overheating issues so I decided to open it up and replace the thermal paste and install a new fan, so far I only have removed the old thermal paste residue using rubbing alcohol and toothpick and tissues. Then I needed to log in to my Windows OS to check on something but now the laptop turns on and shuts off immediately.
Here are some pictures:

https://imgur.io/a/xy3lpax

And a video of when I turn it on:

https://vimeo.com/757919317

I don't have a multimeter, I can't test if any of the components are faulty. My specific question is: Does this laptop which is an Asus N552VW in any way detect that: 1. It's missing a heatsink. 2. It's missing thermal paste. 3. The two cables that are on the third picture are not connected. So that the computer shuts itself off?

Also, you can see that my toothpick has made dome damages to the chips, could this have caused an issue?

Lastly, there are no signs of short circuits or burns, is this a sign of CPU or motherboard being damaged or is this morely a sign of the laptop trying to protect itself?

Comment: You're running without thermal paste? Be thankful that it shutsdown immediately.

Comment: Erm. Do not run your laptop without thermal paste and fan. There is a good chance you will destroy your CPU

Comment: @harrymc hello but I just needed to check something, wouldn't have let it run for more than 5 minutes. Do you think I damaged the laptop with alcohol or the toothpick?

Comment: @davidpostill hello even for 5 minutes? But what did I do wrong? Does the laptop understand that the heatsink is missing thus doesn't turn it on?

Comment: There is no way that I can find out what happened, but you should just know that a CPU without thermal paste can cook itself within seconds.

Comment: [Can You Use a CPU Without Cooler: A Comprehensive Guide | WhatsaByte](https://whatsabyte.com/use-cpu-without-cooler-comprehensive-guide/)

Comment: "You cannot use a CPU without a cooler. CPUs used today will not last for more than a few seconds if booted without a cooling mechanism in place. While CPUs come with an inbuilt throttling system that will shut them down to prevent heat damage, there’s risk of permanent damage if left to run too hot."

Comment: Specific to your questions: `Does this laptop which is an Asus N552VW in any way detect that`.. NO.. not those things.  You are instantly overheating and or damaged something.  It has no problems detecting the heat created by you running without them.  If the cables being hooked up or not is the least of your worries.  `my toothpick has made dome damages to the chips`.. no way to know for sure but the scratches looks superficial assuming that I am looking at the right thing.  You should not try to boot this puppy again without doing what the other people in this forum are advising you of.

Comment: "There is this bridge to cross a river. I removed all the wooden planks that form the floor of the bridge, but now I need to cross the bridge to get something, but when I try to cross the bridge, I fall in the river." Sounds weird, but this is exactly what you did. The thermal paste and cooler are mandatory. They are required. Otherwise... *poof*

Comment: @LPChip hello I still haven't ordered my new fan and thermal paste, I was just making sure I didn't fry the motherboard before I make the order, is there a chance that if I install the new fan and thermal paste, the laptop will boot fine? Otherwise I might have to stop DIY'ing it and just take it to a repair shop which is unfortunate because I would learn nothing from all this.

Comment: @Shayan Although it is hard to say, I would say, chances are 80% that it will still work. Kind of depends on how many times you tried to turn it on. If less than 5 times, its probably still okay although you may have reduced the lifetime of your CPU. But it will power on, as you haven't heard a loud bang and no smoke came out just yet. EG: you haven't blown up your CPU yet.

Comment: @lpchip If you could kindly write an answer so I can accept please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There is this bridge to cross a river. I removed all the wooden planks that form the floor of the bridge, but now I need to cross the bridge to get something, but when I try to cross the bridge, I fall in the river." Sounds weird, but this is exactly what you did. The thermal paste and cooler are mandatory. They are required. Otherwise... *poof*

> I still haven't ordered my new fan and thermal paste, I was just making sure I didn't fry the motherboard before I make the order, is there a chance that if I install the new fan and thermal paste, the laptop will boot fine? Otherwise I might have to stop DIY'ing it and just take it to a repair shop which is unfortunate because I would learn nothing from all this.

Although it is hard to say, I would say, chances are 80% that it will still work. Kind of depends on how many times you tried to turn it on. If less than 5 times, its probably still okay although you may have reduced the lifetime of your CPU. But it will power on, as you haven't heard a loud bang and no smoke came out just yet. EG: you haven't blown up your CPU yet